# How can use multiple function in model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class mypage extends Model
{
   public $rules = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'message' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
   ];

   public $edit = [
    'message' => 'required'
   ];

   protected $table = 'mypages';
}
```

I want to use on controller like this ,
`$validator = validator::make($data = Input::all(), mypage::$edit);`,
`$validator = validator::make($data = Input::all(), mypage::$rules);`

but It brings error like this:FatalThrowableError in MyPageController.php line 59:
Access to undeclared static property: App\mypage::$edit

How can I use like this?

Comment: try using $this->edit

Comment: declare `$rules` and `$edit` as `static` like, `public static $rules` and `public static $edit`

Comment: @kapil.dev not working too

Comment: @LalitThapa then It brings error like:MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 452: mypage

Comment: Then just remove the `static` keyword. Then create the object of your model `$mypage = new mypage();` and use the rules as `$mypage->rules` and `$mypage->edit`

Comment: @LalitThapa sorry for I'm not good at english , you mean `$mypage  = new mypage();``$validator = validator::make($data = Input::all(), mypage::$mypage->rules);` in my controller ?

Comment: Not exactly. At first write `$mypage = new mypage();` then you don't need to do `$validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), mypage::$mypage->rules)`, you can just write `$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $mypage->rules)`

Comment: thank you so much . Have a nice day XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`static` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

```
public static $edit = [
    'message' => 'required'
];
```

Comment: I declare like `public static $rules` and `public static $edit`, then It brings error like: MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 452:
mypage

Comment: You get `MassAssignmentException` because you didn't add `$fillable` array to your model, not because of using `static`.